# Does Gradle has any issue with parsing Jargs.jar

Tags: gradle

I'm using JArgs.jar for the command line parsing. It's working fine without Gradle but when I'm using Gradle to run my tests it's now working. It seems somehow the jar is not copied by Gradle!
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some code in order to get more help.

Comment: And please don't double-post here and on http://forums.gradle.org.